# Swift returning empty list from API

Tags: swift

I'm learning swift and I wanted to pull some data from a django model to work with, so I was following a tutorial on YouTube. I copied the code on YouTube and I got his Breaking Bad API (https://breakingbadapi.com/api/quotes) to display on my simulator, however when I subbed in the URL to my API, I returned an empty list and my simulator displays only a blank screen.
I've tried using both http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/main_course/
and http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/main_course/?format=json

From my terminal I get 200 OK:
[14/Sep/2022 21:28:48] "GET /api/main_course/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1185

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Entree: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var menu: String
    var name: String
    var descripton: String

}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var entrees = [Entree]()

    var body: some View {
        List(entrees, id: \.id) {entree in
            Text(entree.name)
            Text("Run")
        }
        .task {
            await loadData()
    print(entrees)
    }
}
func loadData() async {
    // create URL
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/main_course/") else {
        print("URL Invalid")
        return
    }
    // fetch data from that URL
    do {
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        // decode that data
        if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Entree].self, from: data) {
            entrees = decodedResponse
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Data invalid")
    }
    
   
   }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
       ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Don’t ignore DecodingErrors. They tell you at once what’s wrong.

Comment: Didn't i saw the same question a few minutes ago? And one important comment was to not write `try?`, but `try`? In fact, NEVER USE `try?` if you aren't able to debug it. And print the thrown error: `print("Data invalid")` -> `print("error: \(error)")`

Comment: Note, Apple requires `https` connection. To use `http`, you need to set the "NSAppTransportSecurity" 
 in your `Info.plist` to allow `http` connection to the server? Did you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is on the conversion.
Try using the same keys.

```
struct Entree: Codable {
  var quoteId: Int
  var quote: String
  var author: String
  var series: String

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case quoteId = "quote_id"
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh my God, thank you. I had the wrong data type! You made me look back at that, thank you so much.